# Is there gameplay advantage of adding multiple similar parts to your creature in Spore?

Tags: spore

In Spore, when adding a new part to your creature you gain the abilities that come with it (e.g. charm level 2, sneak level 1). Naturally, adding a better part (e.g. charm level 4) or replacing the older one gives you better ability.

Adding multiple similar *health* parts does seem to increase your total health for each part added. But is there some similar gameplay advantage when adding others kinds of parts multiple times?

*(Of course, much of Spore's attraction is in creating a creature that suits your tastes, so of course there's often a point in adding multiple similar parts. What I'm asking is if there's also a gameplay advantage.)*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

At the creature stage (on land) I'm afraid adding duplicate parts doesn't help you out. Essentially your skill level (charm, melee, etc.) is determined by the part with the highest level (for that skill).

I've experimented with this a fair bit, and does appear to be only be available for aesthetic reasons.

Comment: I was thinking it might affect how fast the skill refreshes or something subtle like that... It'd be pretty strange if it's just for looks for other parts if the amount of *health* parts does add to the overall health.

Answer (score 1):

There are [too many combinations](http://spore.wikia.com/wiki/Cell_Stage) to explain but I can touch a few.

1. Multiple movement parts increase speed, each one giving reducing benefit
2. Multiple mouths give more surface area to attack from. Also, if you have carnivorous mouth at the front and herbivore at the side, then you are effectively an omnivore.

and so on.

But this is just early on in the game, in the cell stage.

These parts start [affecting](http://spore.wikia.com/wiki/Consequence) behavior/traits of the species in the later stages. So if you want to be a peaceful and friendly race, you might want to start off as a herbivore.

Comment: This is true only for the Cell Stage (first).

Comment: i did mention that.

Comment: The consequence link seems to only talk about how *behaviour* (herbi,omni,carni) affects the later stages. Does what *parts* the creature has also have an effect?

Comment: indirectly, yes. If you have a herbi mouth and charm stuff you will be a peaceful creature, OTH, if you have a carni mouth and horns and stuff you will be aggressive, but this can very easily be modified that particular stage

Answer (score 1):

There is absolutely no advantage to adding multiple parts.

Answer (score 1):

In the cell stage, yes.

In the creature or later stages of the game, no.

In creature stage, carnies are "aggressive" because their only source of food is dead animals. Scavenging isn't an actual tactic that can be tried because you get hungry too fast and so few carcasses are around on the map. Herbies are generally peaceful because they don't need to kill other creatures. They can feed on the plants at will, and therefore can take their time when played. They can therefore do the sing/dance/pose to make friends. Carnies could make friends, but they might have to kill them later, just for a meal.

In tribal stage, carnies are aggressive because it is easier. Herbies can just gather plants to stock up on food. Carnies have to hunt. It is possible, once a carnie has food, for the shaman to tame some creatures. But that takes up food which is only obtained by hunting.

Once carnies have the fishing hut, they can gather food by fishing--- but this is generally only useful if their village is close enough to the water that the carry time isn't too long. Otherwise several of the villagers will need to fish, and this weakens the tribes defensive strength.

In the space stage, true carnies have no problem picking off worlds, thanks to their invulnerability shield. It might take a couple of trips, but it is worth the reward of solitude. The space stage is easier to play if you have no allies. You will be interrupted less when you are doing things as you won't have allies that need you to run to their worlds and kill the sick creatures or defend their worlds from Grox or other aggressive species.